# Syntax error for lambda function using pandas

Tags: python, lambda, syntax, syntax-error

Why does the following result in `SyntaxError`?

```
data['Direction'] = lambda x : 'up' if data['Rolling'].shift(1) < data['Rolling'] else ('down' if data['Rolling'].shift(1) > data['Rolling'])
```

Comment: what is the error? (the full text is important)

Comment: You are missing the `else` part for the second `if`. But that won't do what you want either.

Answer (score 0):

You got the `SyntaxError` due to the `('down' if data['Rolling'].shift(1) > data['Rolling'])`. If you want the function to return `'up'` if `data['Rolling'].shift(1) < data['Rolling']` and `'down`' otherwise *(`data['Rolling'].shift(1) >= data['Rolling']`)*, you can do:

```
lambda x : 'up' if data['Rolling'].shift(1) < data['Rolling'] else 'down'
```

Or if you also want the function to return `None` for when `data['Rolling'].shift(1) == data['Rolling']`, you can do:

```
lambda x : 'up' if data['Rolling'].shift(1) < data['Rolling'] else ('down' if data['Rolling'].shift(1) > data['Rolling'] else None)
```

Comment: That is ok if I just wanted to return 'down' for the opposite answer, however 'down' also requires a test and it is the test that is causing the syntax error. I will think about how this is occurring and see if I can modify the query .. thank you very much for taking a look at the problem.

Comment: @JLC Check the second code snippet; it takes care of the test for the `'down'`.